# $P(A \cap B) = \frac14, P(\neg A) = \frac13, P(B) = \frac12, P(A \cup B) =$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

My solution:

$P(A) = 1-P(\neg A) = \frac23$

$P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B) = \frac23\cdot\frac12 = \frac26 = \frac13$

$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = \frac23+\frac12-\frac13 = \frac56$

But the correct answer is $\frac{11}{12}$. Why?

Comment: Thanks for downvote within 2 seconds of seeing my question m8. Really nice piece of human being you are.

Comment: $P(A\wedge B)$ is not necessarily equal to $P(A)\cdot P(B)$. For example, consider $A=B$ and $0<P(A)=P(B)<1$.

Comment: This site encourages that you use proper formatting in your posts. Learn MathJax [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, downvoting implies that you should try to improve your post.

Comment: Your second line is both wrong and unnecessary, since P(A and B) is a given (at least I can see it in the question title).

Comment: Your second line is true if the events $\;A,\,B\;$ are *independent* ...

Comment: Why are so many downvotes seriously? You should realize he is a new user and there is some (maybe little) self effort.

Comment: @msm: You are falsely assuming that there are only intelligent users on this website.

Comment: Downvotes here are free: some people really enjoy clicking on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You correctly state that: $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

Then you *try* to calculate $P(A\cap B)$ from $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ when (a) you do not *know* that they are independent and (b) you already *have* a value of $1/4$ given to you.

Which means that they are not independent, and you don't need to calculate it.

$$\mathsf P(A\cup B) = \tfrac 12+\tfrac 23-\tfrac 14 =\frac {11}{12}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$

We also have that $\;P(\neg A)=1-P(A)\;$ , so...can you see why the answer sheet is correct?

As commented, **if** the events $\;A,\,B\;$ are independent then you can write $\;P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)\;$ , yet you're not given this.